# Drag and drop highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a functionality in my site that'll highlight the drag and drop area for the ease of user.

I dug up a code that is working perfectly on JSFIDDLE. But can't perform any actions on my local server.

I've also included the java script library, but results are as disappointing as earlier tries. I might be missing something.

I'm also giving the link of JSFiddle where the code is in working condition.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ezCEG/)

HTML

```
<div id='container'><div name='drop' style='display: none;'>DROP HERE</div><div name='drag'>DRAG HERE</div></div>
```

jQuery

```
var $dropTarget = $("#container");
$(document).bind("dragover", function(e) {
    if ($dropTarget.hasClass("highlight"))
        return;

    $dropTarget.addClass("highlight");
    $dropTarget.find("[name='drop']").show();
    $dropTarget.find("[name='drag']").hide();
}).bind("dragleave drop", function(e) {
    if (!$dropTarget.hasClass("highlight"))
        return;

    $dropTarget.removeClass("highlight");
    $dropTarget.find("[name='drop']").hide();
    $dropTarget.find("[name='drag']").show();
});
```

CSS

```
#container {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fdd;
    border: 2px solid #fdd;
}
#container [name=drop] {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #dfd;
    border: 2px solid #dfd;
}
#container [name=drag] {
    padding: 10px;
    background: #ddf;
    border: 2px solid #ddf;
}
.highlight {
    border-color: #fc0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to. If there are no errors, look in the network tab of the browser's dev tools and see that all scripts are loaded correctly.

Comment: Is your jQuery wrapped in a document ready call or loaded at the end of the document?

Comment: Also, the jsfiddle doesn't do anything for me (Chrome).

Comment: not working for me either ( safari 6.1.4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked For me-

```
// var $dropTarget = $("#container");
$(document).bind("dragover", function(e) {
    if ($("#container").hasClass("highlight"))
        return; 

    $("#container").addClass("highlight");
    $("#container").find("[name='drop']").show();
    $("#container").find("[name='drag']").hide();
}).bind("dragleave drop", function(e) {
    // alert('asdasd');
   if (!$("#container").hasClass("highlight"))
        return; 
    $("#container").removeClass("highlight");
    $("#container").find("[name='drop']").hide();
    $("#container").find("[name='drag']").show();
});
```

[Also in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ezCEG/2/)

Comment: But it is working here - Chrome 35.0.1916.153 and also in Firefox 30